# How to wait for msSQLdb response on nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, timing

I'm making an aplication that a I need to "res.send()" the SQLdb response. The problem is that my db is sending the response too late. 
Here is my current solution:

```
var sqlres;
function sqldb(SQLquery){

    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();

        request.query(SQLquery, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            sqlres = recordset.recordset;
        });
    });
}

app.get('/db', function (req, res) {
    sqldb('SELECT * from dbo.pontos');

    const timeoutObj = setTimeout(() => {
        res.send(sqlres);
    }, 1500);


});
```

If I remove "setTimeout" here is what i get on the first load:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT7Iz.png)

And here is the second run/result of the code above: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDXPS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using callbacks in this instance, so you need to pass a callback to your `sqldb()` function. so

```
var sqlres;
function sqldb(SQLquery, cb){

    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();

        request.query(SQLquery, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            sqlres = recordset.recordset;
            cb(sqlres)
        });
    });
}

app.get('/db', function (req, res) {
    sqldb('SELECT * from dbo.pontos', (sqlres) => {
        res.send(sqlres);
    });
});
```